# Invoke api's information as a variable in node.js and throw it to html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

seniors! I'm working on a graduation project, and

I could parse the various data with app.js using the public data site API and put it into variables such as no1, no2, no3, no4 ... and run the app.js server, so that it could be displayed in the console window.

However, I want to display the numeric data imported by api in real time by connecting it to a specific part of html !!!!!!!

how do I handle it?  Now, I put the numerical data at random in the source.

---

val: !!!!!!!,

color: '#57B4F2',

click: function(e)

---

data-slno='1' data-min='0' data-max='!!!!!!!' data-delay='10' data-increment="900"

```js
let request = require('request');
let cheerio = require('cheerio');

const $url = 'http://kradata.kra.co.kr:8082/service/api15/getOpenDataList';

const $KEY = '';

const $meet = '1';
const $hr_no = '037703';
const $api_url = $url + '?meet=' + $meet + '&hr_no=' + $hr_no + '&ServiceKey=' + $KEY;

console.log($api_url);

request($api_url, function(err, res, body) {
    $ = cheerio.load(body);
    
    $('item').each(function(idx){
        let no1 = $(this).find('hrName').text();
        let no2 = $(this).find('winRateT').text();
        let no3 = $(this).find('qnlRateT').text();
        let no4 = $(this).find('winRateY').text();
        let no5 = $(this).find('recentRcDist').text();
        let no6 = $(this).find('chaksunT').text();
        let no7 = $(this).find('chaksunY').text();
        let no8 = $(this).find('chaksun_6').text();
        
        console.log(`racehorse : ${no1} \n winning: ${no2}, winning2: ${no3}, winning3: ${no4} \n winning4: ${no5}, winning5: ${no6}, winning6: ${no7}, winning7: ${no8}`);

    });
});
```

```html
<script> 
$(window).load(function() {
  doughnutWidget.options = {
    container: $('#container'),
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    class: 'myClass',
    cutout: 50
  };

  doughnutWidget.render(data());

  setInterval(init, 2000);
});

function init() {
  doughnutWidget.render(data());
}

function data() {
    var data = {
    win: {
      val: 60,
      color: '#57B4F2',
      click: function(e) {
      }
    },
    win2: {
      val: 80,
      color: '#6DED5C'
    },
    win3: {
      val: 90,
      color: '#E63329',
    }
  };

  return data;
}
</script>



 
   <div id="container" class="half-left" role="group"></div>
    <div class='section half-right'>

        <div class='numscroller-info-top'>win4</div>
        <div class='numscroller numscroller-big-bottom' data-slno='1' data-min='0' data-max='2000' data-delay='10' data-increment="900">0</div>
    </div>
    <div class='section half-right'>
        <div class='numscroller-info-top'>win5</div>
        <div class='numscroller numscroller-big-bottom' data-slno='1' data-min='0' data-max='243900000' data-delay='10' data-increment="1000000">0</div>
    </div>

    <div class='section half-right'>
        <div class='numscroller-info-top'>win6</div>
        <div class='numscroller numscroller-big-bottom' data-slno='1' data-min='0' data-max='243900000' data-delay='5' data-increment="598760">0</div>
    </div>
    <div class='section half-right'>
        <div class='numscroller-info-top'>win7</div>
        <div class='numscroller numscroller-big-bottom' data-slno='1' data-min='0' data-max='155700000' data-delay='5' data-increment="987650">0</div>
    </div>
```

I would greatly appreciate you reviewing the code above. I will ask again.

How do I get the data for the variables no1, no2, no3, no4, no5, no6, no7 above in the html file below

val: 80

data-max = '243900000'

Can I get the value of this code part instead of the number?

ex) Instead of 80, no1's integer value

ex) Instead of 243900000, no2's integer value